# How to ensure ntkrnlpa sybmols should get call fom Win7 x64

Tags: windows-7

Have Win7 x64 box, there I want to ensure it should use ntkrnlpa symbols instead of ntoskrnl. 
So far have tried "BCDEdit /set pae ForceEnable " but no luck

Comment: what is your issue? You can use symchk to get the PDB you need.

Comment: symchk will provide what the symbol used by my system, it won't let me decide to chose wither use ntkrnlpa symbols instead of ntoskrnl. if i am not wrong. Actually what I need is to ensure my win7x64 machine should always use ntkrnlpa symbol rather than ntoskrnl

Comment: issue even after setting the PAE forcefully, still my box is calling ntoskrnl symbol instead of ntkrnlpa